# React invalid checksum on home page, not secondary pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a isomorphic React (v.0.13) blog. The home page shows the "checksum is invalid" warning in the console. It's the only page that does this, and I *think* it just started doing this? Also, I don't get this warning on my local machine, only on the live server.

I'm using react-router to handle the routing/data loading, so I don't understand why it's working for other routes, but not my home page.

Any ideas on how to start debugging this? Or what's causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Moment.js is formatting the dates on the home page using the `.fromNow()` method. Once I removed that method, the warning went away.